# Error when checking target: expected x3 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (30, 1, 4)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have the following code:

```
def kerasModelGeneral():
    input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1, 4), name='input_shape')
    x1 = keras.layers.LSTM(100, return_sequences=False, name='lstm_0')(input_layer)
    x1 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name='lstm_dropout')(x1)
    x2 = keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=False, activation="tanh", name='LSTM2')(input_layer)
    x2 = keras.layers.Dense(32, name="dense_LSTM2")(x2)
    x = keras.layers.Concatenate(-1)([x1, x2])
    x = keras.layers.Dense(64, name='x2')(x)
    output = keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='linear', name='x3')(x)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output)
    
    adam = keras.optimizers.Nadam(lr=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mse')
    
    return model


window = 30
model = kerasModelGeneral()

model.train_on_batch(np.reshape(X_train, (window, 1, 4)), np.reshape(Y_train, (window, 1, 4)))
# X_train.shape = Y_train.shape = (30, 1, 4)
```

The model works fine, it does not give me any error. The problem comes when I try to train it.
It gives me this error:

```
c:\users\omar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
   1506             x, y,
   1507             sample_weight=sample_weight,
-> 1508             class_weight=class_weight)
   1509         if self._uses_dynamic_learning_phase():
   1510             ins = x + y + sample_weights + [1]

c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    619                 feed_output_shapes,
    620                 check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 621                 exception_prefix='target')
    622 
    623             # Generate sample-wise weight values given the `sample_weight` and

c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    133                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    134                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 135                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    136                 if not check_batch_axis:
    137                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected x3 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (30, 1, 4)
```

I'm aware of `LSTM` input, that is, if I'm not wrong, `(batch, time steps, features)`. I have an unknown number of training data, but at once I'm passing 30 rows of 4 features each one.

This is an example of `X__train` (same shape for `Y_train`):

```
array([[[1.53570860e+00, 3.83927150e+00, 3.83927150e+00, 6.00000000e+03]],

       [[2.76604066e+00, 5.12197064e+00, 7.67854300e+00, 2.32000000e+02]],

       [[3.74148040e+00, 5.75228782e+00, 7.66089118e+00, 2.50000000e+03]],

       [[4.52006701e+00, 6.12871294e+00, 7.64323935e+00, 2.45030000e+04]],

       [[5.14293630e+00, 6.37966302e+00, 7.63882640e+00, 1.47730000e+04]],

       [[5.64123172e+00, 6.55891308e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 3.00000000e+02]],

       [[6.03986807e+00, 6.69335063e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 6.01400000e+03]],

       [[6.35914783e+00, 6.79811910e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 2.60000000e+03]],

       [[6.61420095e+00, 6.88174854e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 9.92800000e+03]],

       [[6.81824345e+00, 6.95017262e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 9.00000000e+02]],

       [[6.98059486e+00, 7.00682494e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 6.36600000e+03]],

       [[7.11135857e+00, 7.05510098e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 2.70000000e+03]],

       [[7.21596955e+00, 7.09648044e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 8.61200000e+03]],

       [[7.29789314e+00, 7.13175425e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 3.34500000e+03]],

       [[7.36343202e+00, 7.16261883e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 1.82800000e+03]],

       [[7.41586312e+00, 7.18985228e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 1.05440000e+04]],

       [[7.45604282e+00, 7.21356947e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 1.40000000e+03]],

       [[7.48818658e+00, 7.23479011e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 3.22240000e+04]],

       [[7.51566677e+00, 7.25432998e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 1.90000000e+03]],

       [[7.53588574e+00, 7.63516806e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 4.00000000e+03]],

       [[7.55206092e+00, 7.63207899e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 7.97400000e+03]],

       [[7.56323587e+00, 7.62810733e+00, 7.63441344e+00, 4.25700000e+03]],

       [[7.57217584e+00, 7.62634215e+00, 7.63220696e+00, 6.61900000e+03]],

       [[7.57756263e+00, 7.62457696e+00, 7.63000049e+00, 7.00000000e+02]],

       [[7.58363725e+00, 7.62325308e+00, 7.62779401e+00, 2.02600000e+03]],

       [[7.58849694e+00, 7.62192919e+00, 7.62558753e+00, 2.55790000e+04]],

       [[7.59238469e+00, 7.62060530e+00, 7.62558753e+00, 1.42310000e+04]],

       [[7.59549490e+00, 7.61918874e+00, 7.62558753e+00, 2.67730000e+04]],

       [[7.59798306e+00, 7.61786486e+00, 7.62558753e+00, 8.40100000e+03]],

       [[7.60262136e+00, 7.61720291e+00, 7.62558753e+00, 6.00000000e+02]]])
```

I've checked multtiple questions here at stackoverflow but I couldn't fin any valid answer to me, or I'm just blind enough to not see it.
What is the problem there? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it!
It seems like the `Y_train` need to have only 2D. So instead of

```
model.train_on_batch(np.reshape(X_train, (window, 1, 4)), np.reshape(Y_train, (window, 1, 4)))
```

I've done:

```
model.train_on_batch(np.reshape(X_train, (window, 1, 4)), np.reshape(Y_train, (window, 4)))
```

And now it works fine. Although I've solved it, I would like to know if anyone knows why `Y_train` needs to be 2D.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you posted the correct code?

I tried your code and did not have any issues. Code below, you can copy and try it.
Only difference is that I generated some random data.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def kerasModelGeneral():
    input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1, 4), name='input_shape')
    x1 = keras.layers.LSTM(100, return_sequences=False, name='lstm_0')(input_layer)
    x1 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name='lstm_dropout')(x1)
    x2 = keras.layers.LSTM(10, return_sequences=False, activation="tanh", name='LSTM2')(input_layer)
    x2 = keras.layers.Dense(32, name="dense_LSTM2")(x2)
    x = keras.layers.Concatenate(-1)([x1, x2])
    x = keras.layers.Dense(64, name='x2')(x)
    output = keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='linear', name='x3')(x)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output)
    
    adam = keras.optimizers.Nadam(lr=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mse')
    
    return model

m = kerasModelGeneral()

window = 30
model = kerasModelGeneral()
print(m.summary())

X_train = tf.random.normal(shape=(30,1,4))
Y_train = tf.random.normal(shape=(30,1,4))

model.train_on_batch(np.reshape(X_train, (window, 1, 4)), np.reshape(Y_train, (window, 1, 4)))
```

Comment: wow I did not excpet this hahaha. No, it's not working. I'm going to check my shapes again just in case

Comment: I've checked imy code again and it doesn't work

Comment: were you able to run my code? please post your data

Comment: I had to edit some shapes, but yes, I was able to run it! Below this comment is my answer!